# careers.stackoverflow.com my account no longer exists

Tags: support, jobs

I see several other questions about this, but I'm wondering if I "comment" on another thread whether it would actually get attention.

Answer (score 4):

Email the Careers support team - careers@stackoverflow.com.

Most if not all of these (albeit rare) cases require individual attention - we need to know who you are, etc.